# JqGrid Edit Form and Paging not working together on the form

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I edit the grid using the Edit form dialog. I need to reload the grid after I submit the button. I have set the reloadAfterSubmit:true.  This works when I set mtype="POST" on my grid. The grid is reloaded as soon as I submit the edit form. But I cant get the pager to work.

When I remove mtype="POST" , pager will work but the edit form does not refresh the grid. Please give me some inputs.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "../Hdlr.ashx?GetData",
                mtype: "POST",
               colNames: ['Id', 'Short Description', 'Long Description','', ''],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: false },
                    { name: 'ShortDescription', index: 'ShortDescription', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'LongDescription', index: 'LongDescription', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'edit', width: 30, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, editformbutton: true, delbutton: false, editbutton: false } },
                    { name: 'delete', width: 30, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, editformbutton: false, delbutton: true, editbutton: false } }],
                postData: {
                    Category: function () { return $("#Category").val(); }
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    cell: "",
                    id: "0"
                },
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                rownumbers: true,
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'MY GridInformation'
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
        }
```

The pager does not work for this simple declartion of jqGrid. Please help

```
 $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "../Hdlr.ashx?method=GetData",
             mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Category', 'ShortDescription', 'LongDescription'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: false },
                    { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: true },
                    { name: 'ShortDescription', index: 'ShortDescription', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LongDescription', index: 'LongDescription', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true }],
            jsonReader: {
                    cell: "",
                    id: "0"
                },
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                rownumbers: true,
              viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'Caption'
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
        });












    $.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
            editData: { Category: function () { return $("#Category").val(); } },
            url: '../Hdlr.ashx?SaveData',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            viewPagerButtons: false,
            });




I have removed edit and add options. The pager on grid is not working
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Common.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            "use strict";

            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: "../Hdlr.ashx?method=GetData",
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['Id'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 500}],
                jsonReader: {cell: "0"},
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                caption: 'Grid Information'
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
        });
        </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <table id="list">
                </table>
                <div id="pager"></div>
</asp:Content>

    enter code here
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the mtype: Post?

Comment: If I dont give that the form is not reloaded after submitting the edit form

Comment: Setting mtype: 'post' should have nothing to do with disabling or preventing any normal jqGrid operation, there is an error some wheres else.

Comment: What about your pager is not working? Does it not change the page of data you see in your jqGrid? Are you getting any errors on the client side? Are you handing the paging on the server side? Is jqGrid passing the data to your controller to change the page of the dataset?

Comment: Yes I  do server side paging. When I remove the attribute mtype:POST the pager parameters are passed to the server.
But then after submitting the form the grid does not reload to reflect changes.

When I set the mtype:POST the grid is refreshing after edit. But the pagers parameters pageindes, rowsperPage are all passed as NULL

Comment: Sounds like there is an error some wheres for that to be happening.  You could always set the `reloadAfterSubmit: false` and trigger your own reload to see if that works but that is ignoring the underlying error. Why not try building in the edit parameters as part of your grid setup rather then extending the jqGrid settings?

Comment: I have set the edit button on the grid to false.  I have placed the edit icon in a column and set the editformbutton to true. Could you please let me know where to set the edit options

Comment: For a simple declaration of the grid

Comment: I have edited my question again. Can you please take a look. I have a very simple grid now, still my pager is not working with mtype set

Comment: Can you post up the HTML where you setup the grid and the pager element? Possibly try removing the jsonReader as well as I don't think you need it.

Comment: <table><tr>
            <td colspan="3">

                <table id="list">
                </table>
                <div id="pager"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  When I remove jsonreader I get the error, Unable to get the value of property id.

Comment: Why id your jqGrid table inside a table? Are you using the parent table for a layout? if so just remove it to clear that as a source of a problem.  Check as well that you have set the `datatype: 'json'`

Comment: I have a simple grid with one column and still pager is not working I have updated my script above. Please help me figure out

Comment: Still having trouble?

Comment: Yes paging does not work when mtype is set to post. Edit Form does not refresh immediately when mtype is not set to post

Comment: When I looked at the documentation of the jsonReader why again are you using it? If you must use it are you returning the parts of it required to support paging? http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem. Could you please provide me with links to a samplw where you have both server side paging and editing usinng an edit form dialog. Thanks

Comment: My test site at www.nomercymagic.com, and then under the "Collection" menu option includes an edit form by double clicking on a row, and server side paging.  You will have to create a user account to access this menu option however.

Comment: The sample had add, edit , delete and search false on the grid.

Comment: And? I hooked in the edit form via a double click event and then set it up manually so I could do other things to the form.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, rather then extending the jqGrid settings you could build your own edit function to call on press of a button in a row.

```
function EditCollectionItem (rowid, grid){

    $(grid).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
    {
        viewPagerButtons: false,
        editData: { ValueName: value },
        afterShowForm: function (formid) {
            //dostuff here if you wish, ex make a field have focus
        }, //afterShowForm
        afterComplete: function (response) {
          //deal with how the edit went
        } //afterComplete
    }); //$this.jqGrid('editGridRow

}//function EditCollectionItem (rowid, grid){
```

You can set all your other edit options here same as where you were extending them in your original code.